# Finding coordinates of 4th point in a quadilateral

Tags: analytic-geometry

A(1,5), B(4,0), C(-3,-5) are three vertices of a parallelogram ABCD.

Find the coordinates of D, the fourth vertex of the parallelogram

**What I've Done:**I've created the structure on a number plane. I was wondering do you have to find the intersection of AC (These are the points that join up to D)

**Thanks!!**

Comment: Have you perchance heard of the "parallelogram rule" for adding vectors? You can use it in reverse here.

Comment: Can't you just find the intersection?

Comment: I haven't heard of that rule.

Comment: The question is phrased as if there is only one correct answer, but this may not be the case. E.g., if the three given points were $(0,0),(1,0),(0,1)$ then the 4th point could be $(1,1)$ or $(-1,1)$ or $(1,-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Write $\vec{AB}=\vec{DC}$ and solve two equations knowing that $\vec{MN}=(x_N-x_M,y_N-y_M)$.

Comment: What do those arrows mean?

Comment: $\vec{AB}$ is the vector $AB$, do you know what's a vector?

Comment: No I do not! Is that like a vertice?

Comment: Sami, how do you know AB and CD aren't the diagonals of the parallelogram?

Comment: We've drawn the structure on a number plane

Comment: Usually from the order of the letters $ABCD$  we understand that $AC$ and $BD$ are the two diagonals @GerryMyerson

Comment: That may be the intended interpretation, but there's nothing in the statement of the question explicitly supporting that interpretation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 'Nothing in the statement....'? Take any geometric book and if we find: Let ABCD a parallelogram we understand without any doubt that $AC$ and $BD$ are their diagonals.

Comment: A + makes your day a bit smoother. After having a hard work time. Teaching and solving maths is great for us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Distance between two points $P(p_1,p_2)$ and $Q(q_1,q_2)$ in plane is $\sqrt{(q_1-p_1)^2+(q_2-p_2)^2}$

The distance between $D(x,y)$ and $C(-3,-5)$ is equal to the distance between $A(1,5)$ and $B(4,0)$. You can find $x,y$ by  the above formula.

Comment: You are assuming $C$ and $D$ are adjacent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes of course.

Comment: So, that means you are finding only one of the several correct answers. And, anyway, the problem doesn't need distances or square roots.

Comment: I am finding $D$ from the order of letters.

Comment: Fair enough. Still, I think introducing distance overcomplicates the problem.

Comment: May be the problem does not need the things you mentined. But this is an alternative way not the only way. Let the Original poster select his answer from the answers.

Answer (score 0):

To get from A to B, you have to add $(3,-5)$; that is, $$(1,5)+(3,-5)=(4,0)$$ If you add $(3,-5)$ to C, you get one correct value for D.

You get other correct answers if you see what you have to add to A to get to C, and then add that to B, or if you see what you have to add to B to get to C, and then add that to A.